# Best practice to change the route (VueRouter) after a mutation (Vuex)

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I've searched a lot, but there is no clear answer to that. Basically, what should be the best practice to automatically change a route after a mutation?

Ex: I click a button to login() -> action login that makes an http call -> mutation LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL -> I want to redirect the user to the main page `$router.go()`

- Should I wrap the action in a Promise, and then listen to the result to call the route change from the component?
- Should I do it directly from the `$store`?
- Does `vuex-router-sync` helps in any way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this questions seems to be somewhat unclear in the Vue community.

Most people (including me) would say that the store mutation should not have any effects besides actually mutating the store. Hence, doing the route change directly in the `$store` should be avoided.

I have very much enjoyed going with your first suggestion: Wrapping the action in a promise, and changing the route from withing your component as soon as the promise resolves.

A third solution is to use `watch` in your component, in order to change the route as soon as your `LOGGED_IN_USER` state (or whatever you call it) has changed. While this approach allows you to keep your actions and mutations 100% clean, I found it to become messy very, very quickly.

As a result, I would suggest going the promise route.

Answer (score 0):

Put an event listener on your app.vue file then emit en event by your mutation function. But I suggest you wrapping the action in a promise is good way

App.vue:

```
import EventBus from './eventBus';

 methods: {   
    redirectURL(path) {
      this.$router.go(path)}
    },

 created() {
  EventBus.$on('redirect', this.redirectURL)
 }
```

mutation:

```
import EventBus from './eventBus';

LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL() {
  state.blabla = "blabla";
  EventBus.$emit('redirect', '/dashboard')

}
```

Comment: This example is an eligible option. It might need some clarification on used "event bus" pattern. Usually, this is an empty Vue instance shared by all emitters and listeners on that "bus". The imported file `./eventBus` should read like this: `import Vue from "vue"; export default new Vue();`

Answer (score 0):

As of now (mid 2018) API of Vuex supports subscriptions. Using them it is possible to be notified when a mutation is changing your store and to adjust the router on demand.

The following example is an excerpt placed in `created()` life-cycle hook of a Vue component. It is subscribing to mutations of store waiting for the first match of desired criteria to cancel subscriptions and adjust route.

```
{
  ...
  created: function() {
    const unsubscribe = this.$store.subscribe( ( mutation, state ) => {
      if ( mutation.type === "name-of-your-mutation" && state.yourInfo === desiredValue ) {
        unsubscribe();
        this.$router.push( { name: "name-of-your-new-route" } );
      }
    } );
  },
  ...
}
```